# How to disable button with multiple edit text using Textwatcher?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to disable my button if my input edit texts are empty. I am using text watcher for this. To test it out , i have only tried with only two edit texts to start. 
However, my button stays enabled no matter what.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

    fnameInput = findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
    lnameInput = findViewById(R.id.et_lastname);
    numberInput = findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
    emailInput = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    fnameInput.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
    lnameInput.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);


    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchNextActivity();
        }
    });
}
```

Text watcher method

```
private TextWatcher loginTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        String firstNameInput =firstNameInput.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastNameInput = lastNameInput.getText().toString().trim();


        // tried doing it this way 
        nextBtn.setEnabled(!firstNameInput.isEmpty() && !lastNameInput.isEmpty());

        //What i've also tried 
        if(firstNameInput.length()> 0 &&
                lastNameInput.length()>0){
            nextBtn.setEnabled(true);
        } else{
            nextBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

I expect the button to be disabled if one or all inputs are empty and enabled when all input fields are filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method check all condition there like

```
private void checkTheConditions(){
  if(condition1 && condition2)
  nextBtn.setEnabled(true)
  else
  nextBtn.setEnabled(false)
}
```

call this method from `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method

Comment: I set the button.setEnabled(false) on, onCreate to have my button disabled at first view and changed some logic. But other than that, the condition worked when placed afterTextChanged.

Comment: ok, I write this answer putting a few things in mind like validating the user name and checking the password strength. In case you have more than one textWatcher and you are checking different different conditions then this answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider this case for 2 EditTexts only as for now.
define 2 global CharSequence as below

```
CharSequence fName="";
CharSequence lName="";
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

        fnameInput = findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
        lnameInput = findViewById(R.id.et_lastname);
        numberInput = findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
        emailInput = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        fnameInput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        lnameInput.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);


        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchNextActivity();
            }
        });
    }
```

then you have to define different textwatcher for each of your Edittext

then inside each of these textWatcher assign values to CharSequence defined above

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      fName=s;
      validate();  //method to enable or disable button (find method below)

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

now textWatcher2

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher2 = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      lName=s;
      validate();  //method to enable or disable button (find method below)

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

now write validate method

```
void validate(){
        if (fName.length()>0 && lName.length()>0){
            nextBtn.setEnabled(true);

        }else {
            nextBtn.setEnabled(false);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh! You did a small mistake. Use `OR` condition instead of `AND`. So your code should be

```
nextBtn.setEnabled(!firstNameInput.isEmpty() || !lastNameInput.isEmpty());
```

And TextWatcher will only notify when you will manually change the inputs of `EditText`. So TextWatcher will not wark at starting. So at first in `onCreate` method you should manually check those `EditText` feilds.

**Edit:**
Android new DataBinding library is best suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Please go through the Android data Binding library and LiveData. You don't need to write these amount boilerplate codes.